# delete a row in SQLite with a value of null

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to delete all rows in an SQLite Database where the Id = null

Here is my code :-

```
public void deleteNullSongs() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = String.format("ID=%s", null);

    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, sql, null);
}
```

But it does not delete any vlues can't work out what is wrong ?

I have tried different ways of doing this but when i print the contents of the database the rows are still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IS NULL` in your `where` clause:

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID IS NULL", null);
```

Comment: Doh Thanks Marcin